# I am trying to parse string from python regex-Not able parse when string contain ":"

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have

```
string = ":61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL3654628815//CT56748005:86:/BENM/Unitech Imports/REM//58970.047:61:2002190219C30000S103LCADV5674920204//CT56748006:86:/BENM/Gravity Imports/REM//INV/FEB20/446301"
pattern = "61:[A-Za-z0-9 \/,\-_\.]{1,}:86:[A-Za-z0-9 \/\.\-]{1,}"
re.findall(pattern , string) # - > this is giving list with 2 element
```

but when string has **":"** in it, i modified regex to `"61:[A-Za-z0-9 \/,\-_\.:]{1,}:86:[A-Za-z0-9 \/\.\-:]{1,}"`, then its giving full content in one list.

```
modified_string = ":61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL:3654628815//CT56748005:86:/BENM/Unitech Imports/REM//58970.047:61:2002190219C30000S103LCAD:V5674920204//CT56748006:86:/BENM/Gravity Imports/REM//INV/FEB20/446301"
```

I have tried multiple option but not able to get required output.

Expected o/p

```
re.findall(pattern,modified_string)
# => ['61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL:3654628815//CT56748005:86:/BENM/Unitech Imports/REM//58970.047','61:2002190219C30000S103LCAD:V5674920204//CT56748006:86:/BENM/Gravity Imports/REM//INV/FEB20/446301' ]
```

Comment: What part of this is surprising? The ':' is the only thing to indicate where one string stops and the next one starts. As soon as a single match is allowed to _include_ a colon, Python has no way to know that it's not all one long match. Regex functions by default return the longest possible match..

Comment: “Regex functions always return the longest possible match” - not true - by default yes they are greedy but you can very simply modify that by putting ? after the pattern element e.g.`.*` is greedy but `.*?` isn’t - it will try to match the shortest sequence.

Comment: yYup, edited my comment from "always' to "by default". Thanks for the note, @barny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the pattern starts with `61:` and there is a single occurrence of `:81:`, you might use an alternation to match any of the listed chars from the character class `[A-Za-z0-9 \/,_.-]` or only match a `:` when not directly followed by either `61:` or `86:` using a negative lookahead.

```
61:(?:[\w /,.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*:86:(?:[A-Za-z0-9 /.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hasd4X/1)

Comment: `[\w /,.-]` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9 \/,_.-]`

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird. Its working fine.
I also need all the :61 tag which are not followed by :86- 
string = ":61:2002190XCOL3654628815//CT505:86:/BENM/Imports/REM//58:61:2002190219C300S103L:V5674//CT56748006:86:/BENM/Gravity Imports/REM//INV/FEB20/446301:61:200219C30000S103LCADV567204//C7006:"
expected o/p -> 61:200219C30000S103LCADV567204//C7006

Using this regex - 61:(?:[\w /,.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*(?!:86:)* ->This is giving :61 tag which are followed by:86 also.
Pls suggest where i am making mistake, 
Basically i want - string combination of :61:86 tag & :61 string not followed by :86

Comment: @Navneet You could add an anchor at the end `$` to assert the end of the string `61:(?:[\w /,.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*$` https://regex101.com/r/U3MWF7/1 Or you could Use a negative lookahead to assert that after matching 61: there are no more occurrences of :61: and :86: `61:(?!.*(?<=:)(?:61:|86:))[\w /,.-:]+` https://regex101.com/r/z3k3fJ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird  i have tried that - this is only applicable when :61 in the end of string. :61 can be in between also, There are two  :61 tag is below example , this regex parsing only 1.  https://regex101.com/r/U3MWF7/2

Comment: What should it match from the link you provided?

Comment: @Thefourthbird It should match both 61:200219C30000S103LCADV567204//C707, 61:200219C30000S103LCADV567204//C706 - check this updated  regex https://regex101.com/r/U3MWF7/3

Comment: @Navneet Like this? `61:(?:[\w /,.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*(?=:61:|$)` https://regex101.com/r/2svNjG/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Thanks a lot for continuous support, This is applicable for this given example, bt will not work for all kind of scenario, consider :61 tag comes before :60F tag - https://regex101.com/r/2svNjG/1            Basically i need 1. :61:, :86: string which are next to each other  like :61:2002190XCOL3654628815//CT505:86:/BENM/Imports/REM//58 any where in the full message 2. :61 All string which are not followed by :86 anywhere in the full message, message in the regex website is just for example.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Okay , Accepting this answer

Answer (score 0):

The colon appears to be the only indicator that you've hit the end of a match, so allowing a colon to be part of a match removes your delimiter. That said, you can maybe get the desired result by changing your quantifiers `{1,}` to be non-*greedy* (that is, to return the shortest possible match instead of the longest). This is, in general, a somewhat hacky solution and indicates you might need to rethink your parsing strategy. But if you add a `?` after each `{1,}`, you get two matches again.

Also, you can shorten `{1,}` to `+`.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"61:[A-Za-z0-9 \/,\-_\.:]+?:86:[A-Za-z0-9 \/\.\-:]+?")
pattern.findall(string)
#=> ['61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL3654628815//CT56748005:86:/',
     '61:2002190219C30000S103LCADV5674920204//CT56748006:86:/']
```

Comment: Thanks@Mark Reed- i understood now greedy vs non-greedy - but i need content from one :61 tag till next :61 tag, above solution not including full content of :86 tag.